# Geometric Network Build Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, error, topology, geometric-network

I'm trying to create a geometric network of pipes, sewer structures (points) and manholes (points) inside a of an SDE.  I can create the network in a file geodatabase but when I try creating it inside the SDE i get an error about DBMS tables not being found and an error inside the topology engine detected.  Anyone have any insight? I've attached the error screenshot (I think, this is my first post)[image: error]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Would you be able to **edit** your question to include the text, rather than just picture, of your error message, please?  That way it becomes available to future searches by others who may encounter it.

Comment: This thread on GeoNet might have some useful suggestions for you: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/23167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to look in to

1. Check that your SDE DB connection is using the GISADMIN credentials.
2. Check that your Geometric Network was added to the SDE DB using the GISADMIN account.